# Using REF within a FOR expression - unexpected behaviour

Tags: loops, for-loop, abap, internal-tables

I have some example code below:

```
DATA(t_strings) = VALUE char10_t( ( 'S1' ) ( 'S2' ) ( 'S3' ) ).

TYPES : BEGIN OF gty_ref,
         string_ref TYPE REF TO data,
       END OF gty_ref,

       gty_t_ref TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gty_ref.

DATA : t_string_ref1 TYPE gty_t_ref,
       t_string_ref2 TYPE gty_t_ref.

t_string_ref1 = VALUE #( FOR entry IN t_strings ( string_ref = REF #( entry ) ) ).

LOOP AT t_strings ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<entry>).
  t_string_ref2 = VALUE #( BASE t_string_ref2 ( string_ref = REF #( <entry> ) ) ).
ENDLOOP.
```

I thought that using `FOR` or using a loop would provide the same result. But this is what happens:

[image]

Can someone explain why `T_STRING_REF1` only contains references to S3 as opposed to S1, S2 and S3 as I expected?

Comment: Each line of `t_string_ref1` has a reference to the same data object `entry`, so it's normal that all lines show the "last" value of `entry` (in fact, it's the current value, if you change it to another value after the Constructor Expression, all the lines will immediately show that value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entry` in your example is a full-fledged variable. It's not scoped to the FOR-expression. You can still access it afterwards with whatever value it had after the expression.

That means what happens in each loop of your FOR expression is:

1. The value of the current line of `t_string` is copied into `entry`
2. A new structure is initialized, where `string_ref` points to `entry`, not to the line of the table where it got its value from
3. That structure is put into the resulting table `t_string_ref1`

So the result is a table of references which all point to the `entry` variable with whatever value it has at the moment, not into the `t_string` table.

OK, so how to we solve this problem?

The actual crux here is that a `FOR variable IN table` expression behaves like `LOOP AT table INTO variable`. It creates a copy of each line. What you actually need here is to use the equivalent of a `LOOP AT table ASSIGNING <field_symbol>`. Fortunately, FOR can do that by simply declaring the line-variable in `<` and `>`.

```
t_string_ref1 = VALUE #( FOR <entry> IN t_strings ( string_ref = REF #( <entry> ) ) ).
```

Now `<entry>` is no longer a variable but a field-symbol. You can't reference a field symbol. So `REF #( <entry> )` gets you a reference to the table line the field-symbol is currently assigned to.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I didn't know you could use field symbols within FOR expressions.